# How to get language native name (endonym) from country code in C#?

Tags: c#, localization, globalization, cultureinfo

Can I get the language name from country code? I have create a program to let user select localization for currency display purposes. This is the program that do the configuration.

```
CultureInfo[] cinfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
Dictionary<string, string> Misc_dictLocalization = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var sortList = cinfo.OrderBy(p => p.EnglishName).ToList();
foreach (CultureInfo cul in sortList)
{
    //Add country name and bind with country code
    Misc_dictLocalization.Add(cul.Name, cul.EnglishName);
}
Misc_LocalizationCombobox.DataSource = new BindingSource(Misc_dictLocalization, null);
Misc_LocalizationCombobox.DisplayMember = "Value";
Misc_LocalizationCombobox.ValueMember = "Key";
```

On Combobox selection,

```
string key = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)Misc_LocalizationCombobox.SelectedItem).Key;
string value = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)Misc_LocalizationCombobox.SelectedItem).Value;
Misc_CountryCode.Text = key;
decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(Misc_DecimalNumber.Text);
Misc_CurrencyFormat.Text = dec.ToString("C", new CultureInfo(Misc_CountryCode.Text));
```

[image]

I'm currently using

```
var allCultures = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures);
string countrycode = "ar-SA";
string langname = allCultures.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == countrycode).DisplayName;
//langname will have "Arabic"
```

**How to get native name (endonym) from country code?**

Based from the Wikipedia [List of ISO 639-1 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes),
I need to get;

1) Philippines(fil-PH) => Tagalog

2) Vietnam(vi-VN) => Tiếng Việt

3) United States(en-US) => English

4) Arabic(ar-SA) => العربية

**SOLUTION SOLVED (credit Nhan Phan)**
..Exactly like how I would want
[image: Language resources folder]

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Language"));
FileInfo[] Files = di.GetFiles("*.xaml");
int ID = 1;
var allCultures = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures);
LocalizationProperty.LangLoc = new List<AppModel.LanguageLocalization>();
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
{
    string countrycode = file.Name.Replace(".xaml", "").Replace("Resources.", "");
    int index = countrycode.LastIndexOf("-");
    string ISOName = countrycode;
    if (index > 0)
        ISOName = ISOName.Substring(0, index);
    string langname = allCultures.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == ISOName).NativeName;
    AppModel.LanguageLocalization applang = new AppModel.LanguageLocalization
    {
        LanguageID = ID,
        CountryCode = countrycode,
        LanguageName = langname
    };
    LocalizationProperty.LangLoc.Add(applang);
    ID += 1;
}
string langjson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LocalizationProperty.LangLoc, Formatting.Indented);
LogEvents($"[{PageTitle} Language file retrieved. {langjson}", EventLogEntryType.Information);
```

Object2JsonString:-

```
[
   {
      "LanguageID":1,
      "CountryCode":"ar-SA",
      "LanguageName":"العربية"
   },
   {
      "LanguageID":2,
      "CountryCode":"en-US",
      "LanguageName":"English"
   },
   {
      "LanguageID":3,
      "CountryCode":"fil-PH",
      "LanguageName":"Filipino"
   },
   {
      "LanguageID":4,
      "CountryCode":"ms-MY",
      "LanguageName":"Melayu"
   },
   {
      "LanguageID":5,
      "CountryCode":"syr-SY",
      "LanguageName":"ܣܘܪܝܝܐ"
   },
   {
      "LanguageID":6,
      "CountryCode":"ta-IN",
      "LanguageName":"தமிழ்"
   },
   {
      "LanguageID":7,
      "CountryCode":"tt-RU",
      "LanguageName":"Татар"
   },
   {
      "LanguageID":8,
      "CountryCode":"vi-VN",
      "LanguageName":"Tiếng Việt"
   },
   {
      "LanguageID":9,
      "CountryCode":"zh-CN",
      "LanguageName":"中文"
   }
]
```

The view:-
[image: Main select language page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve it via **NativeName** instead of DisplayName:

```
var allCultures = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures);
string countrycode = "ar-SA";
string langname = allCultures.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == countrycode).NativeName;
```