# Are nationalities' local names stored in System.Globalization?

Tags: c#, .net, iso, opendata, opendatabase

In our application the user can view the users, with their nationalities ([demonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym)).
For now the nationalities are displayed in English.

I would like to find a way to display those nationalities in the user's language instead of English.
I searched into CultureInfo or RegionInfo in System.Globalization but I found information and translation only for the languages and the country name.

Would you know a way to do that?
Or a public database / ISO norm which would translate the nationalities names and not only the countries?

I don't want the name of the country in its official language, and the name of the language, I want the name of the nationality those persons have!

Comment: Use [NativeName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909224/how-to-get-language-native-name-endonym-from-country-code-in-c) to get the name of the language in that language.

Comment: I don't want the name of the language, I want the name of nationality in the country's language. For France for example, I want français (which is French in french)

Comment: And e.g. in Belgium, do you look for the french or the dutch demonym?

Comment: @canariJaune - IMHO you are making no sense, first you say `I don't want the name of the language` but than you state `I want français` and `français` is the language which you claimed you don't want.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen the question as the linked duplicate is not about demonyms (nationality names)

Comment: @RandRandom Yes, "francais" is also the language name, but the question is about [Demonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym) which will in many cases not be the same as the language name. E.g. "Irish" (demonym) vs. "English" (language)

Comment: @KlausGütter - oh, I see - than take my reopen vote aswell, consider editing the question and use the correct term

Comment: @Sweeper - see comments above, reopen?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I admit my example was not the best

Comment: A list of the english forms is available [here](https://t2a.io/blog/normalising-nationalities-via-a-good-iso-3166-country-list/) (with CSV). Another one [here](https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/what-is-a-demonym-a-list-of-nationalities.html). I am not aware of any resource providing the demonyms also translated to the local languages. Note that there may be more than one language spoken by people of this nationality (e.g. in Belgium or Switzerland), so there would be multiple translations.

Comment: Yes. Actually I was looking for the traduction of every nationality in every language.